# MVC3 site deployed on IIS6 stops working after 20 minuttes with 404 Not Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6, asp.net-4.0, windows-server-2003-r2

I'll try to make this short, feel free to ask for more details.

A mobile edition a a web-site has been created using MV3 razor and deployed to an IIS6 web-server using extenstionless URL's. Since .NET4 is installed on the server there is no special configuration done on the server to get extensionless urls work. When I try to access the site with the URL: `http://site/m/` i get a `404 Not Found` error.

What I do to produce this problem:

1. Right-click on project in VS2010 and publish to local file system.
2. ZIP all files in and transfer to production server + unzip there
3. Right click on production web-site and add a virtual directory for the new application
4. Create a new application pool with all default settings
5. Put the new virtual directory/application in that application pool
6. Try to access the URL in the browser; receive `404 Not Found`

The thing that puzzles me, is that if I replace Step 1 with "File->Create New MVC3 Project" and then publish to local file system everything works fine:

1. The test-project is displayed in the browser with the name i used `http://site/mvctest/`
2. I do not need to use any extensions
3. It does not stop working after 20 minutes (see next paragraph)

And now for the (even) weirder part:

If I now move the "m" application into the application pool just created for the "mvctest" application; it works too. But only for 20 minutes (or whatever value I have set for "Shutdown worker process after being idle for").

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: If I add wildcard mapping to the `/m/` virtual directory it works, but that should/could also affect performance in a bad way?

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like your first scenario the handler isn't setup to handle the mvc requests. IIS 6 needs to be integrated or an extension for MVC mapped. 
Set the app pool up to run in integrated pipeline mode. What happens then? This should work. Also check the event log for rapid fail protection kicking in because of worker process resets.

Comment: How do I set an IIS6 app pool to integrated pipeline mode? I thought that was an IIS7 feature? Nothing was found in the Event Log.

Comment: ah.. sorry. yea iis 6 is always 'classic' (as per iis 7 definition) as such you _have to_ have the wildcard handler setup for your application to work.

Comment: as for your question on performance - sure - performance could be affected but you need to determine if this is a problem or not. Many sites run like this with no performance issues. Test your app. One option to try is to remove the mapping for any resource folders (scripts, images, etc)

Comment: Are you sure i _have to_ have the handler? From [Phil Haacks](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx) blog: _If you have a server running IIS 6, ASP.NET 4, and ASP.NET MVC 3, your website should just work with the default extensionless URLs generated by ASP.NET MVC applications. No need to configure wildcard mappings nor *.mvc mappings_
Also note that with the default MVC-project `/mvctest/` everything works without any wildcard mapping.

Comment: interesting - this changed as of asp.net 4 because of extensionless urls (our iis6 machines aren't asp.net4). Seems now you don't need it - learn something new every day : )    HOWEVER - according to the post you do need another mapping. I'd check some into this from the post:  "Here’s how the v4.0 ASP.NET extensionless URL features works on IIS 6.  We have an ISAPI Filter named aspnet_filter.dll that appends “/eurl.axd/GUID” to extensionless URLs. " and make sure aspnet_filter.dll is setup correctly.

Comment: The URL for the above item (and also contains some conditions that must be met in order to have this used otherwise you are back to the old way) :   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/06/18/how-to-disable-the-asp-net-v4-0-extensionless-url-feature-on-iis-6-0.aspx